# Vertx JavaScript "ClassNotFoundException" with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, vert.x, vertx3

I am trying to run a Vertx 3.1.0 JavaScript application with IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 7 (64 bit). The IntelliJ configuration is used from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277301/run-vertx-in-an-ide).
[image]

If I use the command line from the diretory "C:\Development\Workspace\Java\vertx\hello" with the command "vertx run JsVerticle.js" everything is working. If I run the application from IntelliJ I got a exception: "Failed in deploying verticle
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JsVerticle.js". If I run a Java application with the program arguments "run company.app.MyFirstVerticle" it is working.

By the way, if I run explicit rhino with the command "vertx run rhino:JsVerticle.js", I get the same exception.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I forgot to add the dependency for the JavaScript language. With maven I use this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-lang-js</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it is running with the IntelliJ IDEA and debugging is working, too!